# Send Mail [PHP]

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am having trouble with my PHP code. I use IF-ELSE to check that everything goes ok but it keeps giving me the "You did not enter a recipient".

```
<?php

$to=trim($_POST['toperson']);
$from=trim($_POST['spoofrom']);
$message=trim($_POST['message']);
$subject=trim($_POST['subj']);


if (substr_count($to, '@') <= 1 ) {
    if (!isset($to)) {
        if (!isset($from)) {
            if (!isset($subject)) {
                if (!isset($message)) {
                    mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $from);
                    print "Message was sent!";
                }else {print "You did not enter a message";} 
            }else {print "You did not enter a subject";}
        }else {print "You did not enter a from email";}
    }else {print "You did not enter a recipient";}
}else{print "You entered 2 or more emails.";}

?>
```

Comment: did you check your recipient's textbox name in the form? Maybe it is mistyped.

Comment: Please learn about mail header injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

replace your conditions `if (!isset($to))` by `if (isset($to))`
And add the empty check

Doc: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Like this:

```
if (substr_count($to, '@') <= 1 ) {
    if (isset($to) && !empty($to)) {
        if (isset($from) && !empty($from)) {
            if (isset($subject) && !empty($subject)) {
                if (isset($message) && !empty($message)) {
                    mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $from);
                    print "Message was sent!";
                }else {print "You did not enter a message";} 
            }else {print "You did not enter a subject";}
        }else {print "You did not enter a from email";}
    }else {print "You did not enter a recipient";}
}else{print "You entered 2 or more emails.";}
```

Comment: that does not make any sense. As there is already an assigment `$to = ...;`, so the isset-call is ALWAYS true (if the key existed e.g. it isn't null). Check for empty...

Comment: @bwoebi: Indeed. The assignment will fail with an 'undefined index' error message is the URL parameter is not present.

Comment: Yes that's what I said: "(if the key existed e.g. it isn't null)". Btw. I don't think he wants to check if the form was manipulated, but if all the fields were filled.

Comment: @bwoebi: But (s)he *should* want to check that, too. E.g., it's easy to inject extra headers through the from-field and send spam to others.

Answer (score 0):

You eventually mean: empty() instead of isset() as it IS always set… but not always filled?

Or check if `isset($_POST['to'])` and the other keys, but don't use isset on assigned variables (a check `is_null` / `=== null` is better there

Answer (score 0):

Your code will send mail if your all form data are empty. 
    `if(!isset($_POST["something"])`
means the conditional process will fire if your data is NOT set.

Remove exclamations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form has proper validation using regex &| html5/css3 prior to form submission. use !empty() verse isset() lastly, I'd suggest putting

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $from)) { 
   print "Message was sent!";
} else { print "email failed to send!"; }
```

Also, I'd put the From: when setting the variable not calling it, but that's more personal preference.

```
$from= "From: trim($_POST['spoofrom'])";
```